# trying to save images Using existing camera apps

Tags: android, file, android-camera

i am new to android and trying to make an app using existing camera.
i am trying to save the image in the dcim directory.
for now the app create a file but no images, how could i advance,how to save the image
thanks in advance

```
======================== CAMERA ===============================

public static class App {
    public static File file;
    public static File directory;
}
private void CreateDirectoryForPictures() {
    File path= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    App.directory = new File(path,"Mahapach_Images");
    if (!App.directory.exists()) {
        App.directory.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
}
private void takeAPicture(){
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    CreateDirectoryForPictures();
    Intent intent =new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    App.file = new File(App.directory,imageFileName);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(App.file));
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
private void choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            //make it available in the gallery
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(App.file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
        else if (requestCode == 2) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.e("path image from gallery", picturePath + "");
                infoWindowImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find many tutorial by just google, and that can do your task like this one i found [here](https://androidkennel.org/android-camera-access-tutorial/)

OR

There is better way, use Easy Image library which can do your task with ease [click here](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage) but remember you have to take care of permission for marshmallow and above android versions.